# Vue.js - update dom after object property updates

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This drives me crazy. Dom with `v-model` won't update with object properties, but Vue devtools does update correctly.

I learned from somewhere that this may require `Vue.$set`, which seems impossible in `v-for` iterations.

```
<el-tab-pane v-for="(item, index) in onShelveForm.data" :key="item.id" :label="item.name">
  <div class="form-block" v-for="formItem in formStructure">
    <el-form-item
    :prop="'data.' + index + '.' + formItem.id"
    :label="formItem.name">

      <el-select
        v-model="item[formItem.id]"
        readonly="false">
        <el-option v-for="option in formItem.value.regex"
          :label="option"
          :value="option"></el-option>
      </el-select>

    ...
```

When I click an option, the selector doesn't show the new value, but Vue devtool reacts correctly.

If `Vue.$set` could save this, how would I use it in `v-for`?

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle pls. Also if `el-select` is your custom `select` element - it will not handle `v-model`.

Comment: it can handle `v-model` if he will provide it

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide a jsfiddle, it may be easier to see why the `v-model` is not working.

There are a few possibilities, such as the object not being present when the instance created.

The simplest way may be to just force an update when the change happens by adding `@change='Vue.$forceUpdate()'` , but this more of a hack than a solution. The `v-model` should work

```
<el-select
    @change='Vue.$forceUpdate()'
    v-model="item[formItem.id]"
    readonly="false">
    <el-option v-for="option in formItem.value.regex"
      :label="option"
      :value="option"></el-option>
</el-select>
```